# Selecting particular data from SQL SERVER VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a VIEW in SQL SERVER 2012, with the following fields. ID, Label, FLdName, Insurance, AddedON. There are some duplicate ID's in the field. I'm trying to simply SELECT against the view so that it only shows me the latest ADDED on date, this would only show me a single instance of ID in case there are more than 1. So for example I have an id 1359 - that has 2 added on dates 1/3/2015 and 8/10/2015. I only want to select the max date (8/10/15), however, for all the other ID's where there is only one instance of it, i want to make sure gets selected as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by addedon desc) rn
    from yourview
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Ths is great, finally works. Can I do this in VB6, in my select statement?

Comment: @SamSam7 -- yes you can.  You may want to look into using stored procedures instead of in-line sql in your code, but that's a different conversation.

Comment: Tried it works perfectly! You are the best! I was sitting her for a quite sometime trying to figure it out.